# User scope environment variable: PATH append string value to existing value

Tags: windows-7, command-line, bash, environment-variables, path

I want to know, how to to append value to existing PATH variable (user scope):

```
SETX PATH "%PATH%;D:\Myfolder\Test\"
```

The above script takes system path variable data using `%PATH%` and append my folder path (`D:\Myfolder\Test\`) to PATH (user scope).

My need is to take user path variable before append. I need a fix for this case.

Please provide your suggestion.

Answer (score 2):

Just making sure I understand correctly: you want to edit the user-scope PATH variable, but don't want to add all the stuff from the system-scope copy of PATH to your user-scope one?

The best way I know of to do this is actually to use Powershell. Yes, I know you tagged this as `bash`, but I'm pretty sure you didn't mean to; `setx` is a Windows command. :-)

`[System.Environment]::GetEnvironmentVariable("PATH","USER")` will get the current-user-scope PATH environment variable as a string. You can then append to this and store it back using the `SetEnvironmentVariable` function.

```
$userpath = [System.Environment]::GetEnvironmentVariable("PATH","USER")
$userpath = $userpath + ";D:\Myfolder\Test\"
[System.Environment]::SetEnvironmentVariable("PATH",$userpath,"USER")
```

You can read more about messing with environment variables at [this SuperUser question](https://superuser.com/questions/966074/powershell-environment/966085).

Note that, like the `setx` command, **this won't actually change any environment variables *in the current process***. If you want to do that, you can use `"PROCESS"` instead of `"USER"` in a call to `SetEnvironmentVariable`, or just append your value to `$ENV:PATH`, something like `$ENV:PATH = $ENV:PATH + ";D:\Myfolder\Test\"`

Comment: Good understanding. I don't know about Powershell script .Shall we create a Powershell script file which contains these scripts (your 3 lines) and single click on this file to achieve our functionality.Is there such any possibility?

Comment: You would need to alter the script trust rules (or sign the script) for it to just work by double-clicking a .PS1 file, but you could. You could also use the `-Command` argument to Powershell, similar to the `/C` argument in CMD, to tell it to run just one particular command. You could combine the three lines into a single line (either by nesting commands, or by separating with `;` semicolon characters). You could then tell PS to run that whole thing with one line of CMD.